# Is there a way to write a method that outputs the number of digits before the decimal point of a float parameter as a short?

Tags: java, methods, short

I need to output the total number of digits before the decimal point of a float number and output the results as a short.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    DigitsBeforeDot(18.879);

}

public static short DigitsBeforeDot(float x){
    
    short a = (short) x;
    
    System.out.println((short)Math.log10(a)+1);
    
    return a;
}
```

I get a suggestion to cast the argument in the method to a float like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    DigitsBeforeDot((float) 18.879);

}
```

And this makes the program work but I need to make it work without the casting by changing something in the method.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: How about `18.879f` ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Stick to naming conventions. `public static short DigitsBeforeDot(float x){` should be `public static short digitsBeforeDot(float x) {` or even better: `public static short getDigitsBeforeDot(float x) {` or `public static short calculateDigitsBeforeDot(float x) {`
2. Use a source code formatter if your IDE provides one
3. Instead of working with `float` and `int`, go with `double` and `long`. Apart from storing values in arrays (RAM consumption) there is no downside to using the full register width (64bit) of modern platforms. The upside is that you're a lot less likely to run into problems with precision or overflows.
4. It's highly unlikely that you want partial/float/fractions of the number of digits (like `2.176` as a result for `log10(150)`). It's a lot more likely you want the integer number returned, i.e. `2`. So you should use an byte/short/int/long as return value. I recommend usnig `long`: `public static long calculateDigitsBeforeDot(double x) {`, and instead of casting the log10 to a `short`, you just cast it to a `long` instead. Java always rounds towards zero, so that would equal a call to `Math.floor(Math.log10(a)) + 1`
5. Why is casting not an option for you?

Comment: This is actually a question from a uni test but I didn't wanna specify. So I actually don't see the main string but it's already there and I can't edit it and I have to make a method that takes in a float parameter , for example x, and returns the number of digits before the decimal point as a short. I or no one I knew could figure it out and I just resulted to asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, change the signature of the method to take a `double`.

```
public static short DigitsBeforeDot(double x) {
    short a = (short) (Math.log10(x) + 1);
    System.out.println(a);
    return a;
}
```

Also, it seems really counter productive to pass a `float` or a `double` only to cast to a `short`.